# Passing parameter variable in exec() function in procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to use the parameter variable `exec()` in my procedure.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CostBudgetedTabular](@start  AS datetime)
AS
BEGIN
    Exec('Declare @tempActual Table(MonthName nvarchar(MAX),Total float);
    Declare @tempBudgeted Table(MonthName nvarchar(MAX),Total float);

    insert into @tempBudgeted sp_CostBudgetedTabular @start
    insert into @tempActual sp_CostActualTabular @start  ')
```

It is throwing errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
> Incorrect syntax near 'sp_CostBudgetedTabular'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
> Incorrect syntax near 'sp_CostActualTabular'.

`sp_CostBudgetedTabular` and `sp_CostActualTabular` are procedures which take a date as parameter

Comment: Side note: [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures"

Comment: Also, why are you doing an `EXEC` on an entirely static string? Why not just have the code directly in this procedure?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for the advise , I will keep it in mind   while creating procedures next time. Can you please help me with the issue i am having currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CostBudgetedTabular]
(
    @start DATETIME
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = '
    DECLARE @tempActual TABLE ([MonthName] NVARCHAR(100), Total FLOAT)
    DECLARE @tempBudgeted TABLE ([MonthName] NVARCHAR(100), Total FLOAT)

    INSERT INTO @tempBudgeted
    EXEC dbo.sp_CostBudgetedTabular @start

    INSERT INTO @tempActual
    EXEC dbo.sp_CostActualTabular @start  '

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@start DATETIME', @start = @start

END
```